# Reading a word or regular expression from the mini-buffer to a function

Tags: minibuffer, read

What function should I call to read a word or regular expression from the minibuffer?  Am writing a function that accepts a word or regular expression and counts the number of matches.

But need to change `(char-to-string word)` so the code can match a regular expression rather than a char.

```lisp
    (defun rk-regex-count (regex reg-beg reg-end)
      "Count times a regular expression exists.
    
    REGEX     Regular expression.
    REG-BEG   Marker defining start of region.
    REG-END   Marker defining end of region.
    
    Usage
          M-x rk-regex-count"
    
  (interactive
   (list (read-regexp "Regex: ")
     (region-beginning)
     (region-end) ))

  (save-excursion
    (let ( (a 0) )

      (goto-char reg-beg)
      (while (and (< (point) reg-end)
                  (re-search-forward regex reg-end t))
        (cl-incf a))

      (message "Marks: %s Count: %d" open a)
      (goto-char reg-beg))) )
```

Comment: A regular expression is represented by a string, and so is a word (however you define that). Read the section in the Elisp manual entitled [Reading Text Strings with the Minibuffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-from-Minibuffer.html).

Comment: I see three functions that can be used `read-from-minibuffer`, `read-string`, `read-regexp`, but having difficulty deciding what's the appropriate to use.

Comment: Your question is too vague - it allows no way to guess which of those functions might be more appropriate for your use case. So you answered your own question in your comment: each of those functions works.

Comment: Now the question does not ask a question :-) If the stuff you added to the question (the second and third paragraphs and the code) is supposed to answer the question, then *you should put all that into an answer*  (you can [answer your own question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)). Just cut-and-paste it into the `Your Answer` box below and delete it from the question.

Comment: The frustrating part is that SE customarily disallows a user to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three basic functions that can be used `read-from-minibuffer`, `read-string`, and `read-regexp`. The advantage of `read-regexp` is that it does not require escaping regular expressions as strings require.

Comment: Notwithstanding that you *should* use `read-regexp` for reading a regular expression, I don't believe there are any "escaping" benefits over `read-string`.  In both cases the user gets to input a string verbatim rather than in string read syntax.  For the listed functions, you would only be using string read syntax if you used `read-from-minibuffer` with a non-nil READ argument.